# How to set Android maven project local dependency?

Tags: android, maven, bitcoin

I am working on bitcoin in android. I am trying to build project using maven in windows 7 64 bit. I have done all the process to build the project from this [GitHub Link](https://github.com/schildbach/bitcoin-wallet). Steps what I have done are as below :

**Step: 1** – Download android wallet from GIT from above link

**Step: 2** – Install maven in my Widows pc

**Step: 3** – Set environment variables

**Step: 4** – open command prompt go to directory where android wallet putted. Run command ‘**mvn clean install**’

**Step: 5** – Got the following error :

```
Scanning for projects...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Bitcoin Wallet 4.05-test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.760 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-11-05T18:32:30+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wallet: Could not resolve dependencies for project de.schildbach.wallet:wallet:apk:4.05-test: Failure to find com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0 in file://C:\Android SDK\sdk/extras/android/m2repository was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of android-support has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
D:\Working Point\Bitcoin work space\wallet>
```

**Step: 6** – For the above error Find solution from here - [Link](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer/blob/master/README.markdown)

**Step: 7** – Successfully build maven-android-sdk-deployer

**About Query**

As above tutorial say I have founded local repository (~/.m2/repository/) in my local USER directory in my pc. And Second, that library is not available in maven-central, it ships with the Android SDK. I need to manually deploy it to your local maven repository.

But still can't understand that where I can found it in my case. I am still getting error : The POM for com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available.

**From where to take com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0 jar file ?**

**And where should I put in my android project?**

Please can anybody please tell me where I am making mistake or what should be the next step to successfully build bitcoin wallet android project in maven? Any suggestions, reference or explanation will be much helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

> From where to take `com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0` jar file ?
>   And where should I put in my android project?

`com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0` and `com.android.support:support-v13:jar:19.1.0` is supplied directly by the Android SDK, but not installed automatically when you deploy the SDK on your machine :(

Obtain the JAR files as follow:

1. cd "your android SDK location"/tools, i.e. `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools`
2. Launch the Android SDK Manager: `./android`
3. Install from the menu system: "Extras->Android Support Repository".

   This installs the maven support into `/opt/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository`
4. Before building projects with maven, set the environmental variable to your Android SDK:

   ```
   $ export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
   ```
5. Inside your project source code directory, force maven to update its repositories:

   ```
   $ mvn clean install -U
   ```

This should now build without complaints about `com.android.support:support-v4:jar:19.1.0` 
being missing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have got the answer from doing so many experiments. I have downloaded [support-v4-r7.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/support-v4/r7) from net and then update my android project wallet pom.xml file by replacing following tag

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>19.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

To

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>r7</version>
</dependency>
```

And Its done.